# How to find the PageDirty function or macro definition in the Linux source code？

Tags: c, linux

In line 458 of the fs/proc/task_mmu.c file in the Linux source code, there is the following code:

```
for (i = 0; i < nr; i++, page++) {
    int mapcount = page_mapcount(page);
    unsigned long pss = (PAGE_SIZE << PSS_SHIFT);

    if (mapcount >= 2) {
        if (dirty || PageDirty(page))
            mss->shared_dirty += PAGE_SIZE;
        else
            mss->shared_clean += PAGE_SIZE;
        mss->pss += pss / mapcount;
        if (locked)
            mss->pss_locked += pss / mapcount;
    } else {
        if (dirty || PageDirty(page))
            mss->private_dirty += PAGE_SIZE;
        else
            mss->private_clean += PAGE_SIZE;
        mss->pss += pss;
        if (locked)
            mss->pss_locked += pss;
    }
}
```

Is PageDirty a macro definition or a function? How to find its definition?

Comment: Better than google for this kind of search requests: https://lxr.missinglinkelectronics.com/linux/fs/proc/task_mmu.c#L456

Comment: Thank you! I found 38 calls, 0 defined, so I don't understand what PageDirty() is. My own level is very poor, I have just been in contact with programming for a long time...

Comment: I'd first run `ctags -R` from the root of the source tree. Then open the file in vim, move the cursor over `PageDirty`, and hit `Ctrl-]`, which should jump to the definition of the identifier.

Comment: Ctrl + ] did not jump, the display could not be found

Answer (score 1):

```
find /usr/src/linux -type f -print0 | xargs -0 grep $'^[^ \t].*PageDirty'
```

The path is probably wrong but the rest of this should copy/paste now assuming your shell is bash. If your shell doesn't support [$'](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting) (you won't get an error) you'll have to revert to embedding a literal tab.

What we are looking for is a global definition line containing PageDirty. On typical c styling, only includes, global definitions, and global comments don't start with space or tab. You will still get a few extra hits. It will be obvious which one is right from the grep output.

I fact PageDirty() is a macro that expands to a bit test on the page metadata structure. The `find` line above will find a `#define PageDirty` line in a header file.

What `PageDirty()` does is pretty clear from the code fragment. It checks if the page its passed as an argument is dirty (that is, needs to be written to disk before being discarded) or not.

Comment: What's wrong with `grep -r $'^[^ \t/].*PageDirty' /usr/src/linux`?

Comment: @melpomene: Never seen `$'` is that a typo?

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting

Comment: @melpomene: Nice to learn something new. Now he can copy/paste answer.

Comment: Usually you'd use a tool like `rg` / `ag` / `ack` for searching source code. They know how to recurse by default (and skip version control directories like `.svn` or `.git`).

Comment: @melpomene: I don't want to get into too much of a tools debate, but I did check my system and none of those are in the default install nor build-essential nor build-dep (just about anything).

Comment: "default install" is for normal users, not developers. `build-essential` is the bare minimum to compile software, not a recommended or even good set of dev tools.

Comment: Searched all the relevant header files without the macro definition of PageDirty, I mainly want to see how it is implemented to judge the dirty page, the relevant information I found:       https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/pagemap.txt                               I thought it was judged by if (flags & (1 << 4)), the result page is dirty, all 0